# Crystal Reports printing from remote database - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I have a WPF application which connects to a remote database over internet and print records using Crystal reports. When I connect to a local database, it prints fine. But when connected to the remote database, it just hangs. Is there a way to increase the time out period in CR?

```
           ReportDocument oReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            oReportDocument.Load(GV.strExePath + "\\Reports\\Labeller.rpt");

            lstDockets.Clear();
            lstDockets.Add(oTblBagLabel);                
            oReportDocument.SetDataSource(lstDockets);                    
            oReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with larger cache duration of crystal report source.

like this

```
CrystalReportSource1.CacheDuration = 6000
```

Comment: Hi Jodha, thanks for ur answer. Just wondering where do I specify this in code?

Comment: this code was in my older app. you need to google forcacheduration in crystal report. this will definatly solve your problem